# Luks encrypted external disk does not have any free space

Tags: external-hard-drive, disk-space, luks, du

I have a luks encrypted external disk that worked normally al the time. But suddenly, there is no free space at all. Even when I delete something with `rm bigfile` there is no freed space.

I looked up how much space the disk contains with

```
du -hs /media/user/disk
```

and it returned 876GB, but its a 1TB Disk, with no available space so far..

```
$df -h
#/dev/dm-3                    917G  876G     0 100% /media/user/disk
```

and

```
$df -i
#/dev/dm-3                    61046784 2537248  58509536    5% /media/user/disk
```

Comment: `df -h` and `df -i` say?

Comment: edited the question to add the command outputs

Answer (score 0):

By default when a ext2/3/4 volume is formatted 5% of the space is reserved for exclusive use by root. This prevents the volume from becoming *completely* inaccessible if a user fills up all the space.

This can be changed with the `-m` option to `mke2fs` when formatting the volume or to `tune2fs` after it has been formatted.

Comment: But how could I then put the data there, that now does not generate new space when i delete it? Ok, I can try to move/delete 10GB and see what happens then...